# How to react to journald events err, crit, alert, emerg?

Tags: logging, signals, systemd-journald

Is there a signal/event I can set up a listener/handler/callback for when a message is logged with journald? I need to print add'l diagnostic information at precisely the moment the message is produced. Specifically, my Raspberry Pi has been dying recently with the  kernel producing message `mmc0: PIO read timeout - EDM 10801` and I want to log a message immediately after which indicates if there's an undervoltage.